# The webpage does not display the db contents

Tags: php, mysql, database

Iam trying to display contents from the database. 
No values are getting displayed.
Why does my code not work? I have xampp server running too !

```
<html>
<body>
<?php$username="";$password="";$database="login";
mysql_connect("localhost:170",$username,$password);
@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");
$query="SELECT * FROM logindetails";
$result=mysql_query($query);
$num=mysql_numrows($result);mysql_close();?>
<table border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
<tr>
<td>
<font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Value1</font>
</td>
<td>
<font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Value2</font>
</td>
</tr>
<?php$i=0;while ($i < $num) {$f1=mysql_result($result,$i,"Username");
$f2=mysql_result($result,$i,"Email");?>
<tr>
<td>
<font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo '$f1'; ?></font>
</td>
<td>
<font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo '$f2'; ?></font>
</td>

</tr>
<?php$i++;}?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `username="";` that means there is no user !! are you able to connect to database ?? may be you should use `username="root";`  .

Comment: Why are there no spaces between your opening tags and your variables `<?php$...`?

Comment: Also, remove the quotes around your variables when echoing -> `<?php echo $f1; ?>` instead of `<?php echo '$f1'; ?>`

Comment: okay @Sean ! but when i save the page as **.php, why does it start installing the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the 'mysql_connect' has been deprecated from PHP 5.5 and if you're running PHP 7.0 is has been removed. You will want to use [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

I do not believe there is much difference between the two other than PDO can connect to other databases other than MySQL, whereas, MySQLi can only connect to MySQL.

As to helping you fix your code. This should be close to what you need. I hope it helps

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
$username="root";
$password="password"; // 'password' set to whatever it is on your DB
$database="login";

$dbc = @mysqli_connect("localhost:170",$username,$password)
    OR die( "Unable to select database");


$query="SELECT * FROM logindetails";

$result=mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

$row= mysqli_fetch_array($result);

mysqli_close();
?>
<table border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
<tr>
<td>
<font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Value1</font>
</td>
<td>
<font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Value2</font>
</td>
</tr>
<?php
    //$i=0;while ($i < $num) {$f1=mysql_result($result,$i,"Username");
    //$f2=mysql_result($result,$i,"Email");
?>
<tr>
<td>
<font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo "$row['Username']"; ?></font>
</td>
<td>
<font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo "$row['Email']"; ?></font>
</td>

</tr>
<?php
    //$i++;}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Its not working !!! .... To run a database connectivity with the website , just installing xampp would be sufficient right ? Should i install php into my PC that i am working on ?

Comment: Sorry to take so long to reply. Have you created a database? You need to create a database along with some tables to allow data entry.
I suggest this YouTuber videos ([MySQL](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yPu6qV5byu4) and [MySQL and PHP](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mpQts3ezPVg)) that helped me understand the interaction a bit better between PHP, MySQL, and HTML.

Comment: Yeah !! i did put up the db !! I solved the problem already ! i had problems with php running !

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo in your php:

```
$num = mysql_numrows( $result );
```

There is not a `mysql_numrows` function, change-it in:

```
$num = mysql_num_rows( $result );
```

**Please also note:**

> **mysql_** was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the **[MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)** or **[PDO_MySQL](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php)** extension should be used.

(from PHP Official site)